# boolean model propertie's values not bind in POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have table record as follows

[image]

this how those two properties defined in model classes

```
    public bool? Report_Users { get; set; }
    public bool? Innovation_Discussion_User { get; set; }
```

this is `Form` syntax that used to populate Boolean values in checkboxes

```
            @Html.CheckBox("Report User", Model.Report_Users.GetValueOrDefault(), new { @value = "false" }) Report User
            &nbsp; 
            @Html.CheckBox("Innovation Discussion User", Model.Innovation_Discussion_User.GetValueOrDefault(), new { @value = "false" }) Innovation Discussion User
```

This is check boxes view of that form

[image]

but once I submit , I can see in model those two properties values getting null in POST method

How can I bind this check-boxes values to Boolean property fields, properly ?

Comment: Did you not read my comment to your last question. This will not work! For a start your creating a input with `name="Report"` which has no relationship to your model. And to repeat, a checkbox is for binding to a `bool`, not `bool?`

Comment: How do you suppose indeterminate state will be rendered? What do you suppose to get back in your form? If in HTML you want to see only true/false then to be **wrong** is your ViewModel (is it your ViewModel, _right_?) If it's not then now you know what's wrong: add a ViewModel (with bool) and keep your Model out of your View.

Comment: `creating a input with name="Report"` I cannot understand it ?

Comment: Look at the html your generating! (you have to learn to debug your code). It would need to be `CheckBox("Report_User", ...)` (underscore) to generate the correct `name` attribute. But don't do it. If you want a `nullable` value then use `EditorFor(m => m.Report_User)` which display a dropdown with 3 values, otherwise make you property `bool`

Comment: once I make all `bool?` to `bool` then getting following error in `@Html.CheckBox("Report User", Model.Report_Users.GetValueOrDefault(), new { @value = "false" }) Report User` this line

Comment: Because `bool` does not have a method named `GetValueOrDefault()`. Use just `@Html.CheckboxFor(m => m.Report_User)` if you have changed it to `bool`. If the value of `Report_User` is `true`, your checkbox will be checked, otherwise it will be unchecked. And NEVER set the `value` attribute.

Comment: okay thanks its working , why dont you post as an answer, happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a a number of issues with you implementation.

Your `CheckBox("Report User", ...)` method is generating a checkbox (and associated hidden input) with `name="Report"` and your model does not contain a property named `Report`. Because no value is posted back for `Report_Users`, its value will always be its default (`null`) in the POST method. In order to bind to `bool? Report_Users` then it would need to be `CheckBox("Report_User", ...)` (underscore not space).

Changing that however means the value of `Report_User` now always be `false` instead of `null` because you have added `new { @value = "false" }`. The `CheckBox()` method generates 2 inputs, `<input type="checkbox".. value="True" />` and `<input type="hidden".. value="False" />` in order to correctly bind to your property. You have now overridden it to generate `<input type="checkbox".. value="false" />` so a value of `false` is posted even if the checkbox is checked.

But the real issue with your code is that your property is `bool?` (nullable) and `CheckBox()` is designed to bind to `bool`. typeof `bool?` has 3 states (true/false/null) whereas a checkbox has 2 states (on/off or true/false). Its not clear why your database property is nullable, but if you cannot change it, then (as always), use a view model with a `bool` property. In the GET method, when mapping your data model to the view model, you can use

```
myViewModel.ReportUser = myDataModel.Report_User.GetValueOrDefault();
```

and now you can build you view correctly using the strongly typed helper

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ReportUser)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ReportUser, "Report User") // use a label
// or add [Display(Name="Report User")] and use @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ReportUser)
```

What to learn from this:

1. If your model is not binding, always check the html your generating
   (the `name` attributes of the form controls must match the name of
   the property)
2. Always use the strongly typed `xxxxFor()` HtmlHelpers to generate
   form controls. Not only do you get intellisense, it ensures that the
   correct `name` attributes are generated, and any errors are reported
3. Never attempt to change the `value` attribute when using the
   HtmlHelpers (or the `name` attribute). The helpers generate the
   correct html based on the model property and changing them from the
   default values will only lead to model binding failing